# PythonSelenium how to handle pagination in a table

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am new with python-Selenium, I need to read from a table the third column of each row. My table is paginated.
Can you please help me how to write this code please.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEcMg.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: could you provide the full html code of the table?